# Construct all `r`-tuples with two nonzeros

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

Given an int value `val` and a tuple length `r`, I need to create all `r`-tuples that have `d` of  `{+val, -val}` and the rest filled up with zeros. With `d=2`, I can do

```py
val = 7
r = 5

out = []
for i0 in range(r - 1):
    for i1 in range(i0 + 1, r):
        for v0 in [+val, -val]:
            for v1 in [+val, -val]:
                t = [0] * r
                t[i0] = v0
                t[i1] = v1
                print(t)
```

```py
[7, 7, 0, 0, 0]
[7, -7, 0, 0, 0]
[-7, 7, 0, 0, 0]
[-7, -7, 0, 0, 0]
[7, 0, 7, 0, 0]
# ...
```

but this already feels messy. It's getting worse for larger `d`. I looked at [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) combinatoric iterators, but none of those seems to help.

Any hints?

Comment: How did none of the itertools function seem to help?? It's like the textbook problem to showcase them!!

Comment: @Stef Seems that `more_itertools` is the key here.

Comment: Not really; the simplest way to solve this is with `combinations(range(r), d)` and `product((-val, +val), repeat=d)`, both from itertools, where `combinations` gives the indices where to plug in the +val and -val from `product`. However, plugging values at indices like this is relatively tedious in pure python in my opinion (KellyBundy has magic tricks for it though) (I say "pure python" by opposition with "python + numpy" where you can write `t[I] = V` directly)

Comment: @Stef I actually removed my "magic trick" to be closer to the original. I find neither way particularly tedious, though yes, it's not as neat as NumPy (where I might try `for t[I] in product(...): print(t)` :-)

Comment: @Stef [Tadaa!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVBBboNADLzvK3xcFMihUpQqEg_gDRGHbVjalcC2jIlEvpILl_ZPeUT_UFPIIT7MwTNjj33_4Um_COf5e9S2eH_8tkI9JI2iRN0AqWcSBRZqxovmcKH-I2HQRDi4jcSx5wnCAMjOXUMHJRydGB5cY_jmXEsCFSR8sXsJ-Bm9ZDk02cmBVWVy5H0QCZOvsv-err1bFDKLaXXiWCbUlV5G67mql-lbSn_eWYocCsM6B4kcg5bPHUuxmN9rth693f78wR8) (Not sure why I need to make `I` an array, that's disappointing.)

Comment: @KellyBundy You don't need an array, it works with a list too. But it doesn't work with a tuple because tuples are interpreted as coordinates in a multidimensional array, rather than as a list of coordinates in a one-dimensional array. In other words I think that numpy makes no difference between `t[(1, 2)]` and `t[1, 2]`; so you need `t[[1, 2]]`.

Comment: @Stef Ah, yes, of course. I think NumPy *can't* make a difference between `t[(1, 2)]` and `t[1, 2]`, as *Python* already makes them the same before giving it to NumPy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

- [combinations_with_replacement((-val, +val), d)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) to get all unordered d-uplets of val and -val;
- [more_itertools.distinct_permutations](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.distinct_permutations) to pad with (r-d) zeroes in all possible ways.

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, chain
from more_itertools import distinct_permutations

def combs_with_zeroes(val, d, r):
    if r < d: return iter(())
    return chain.from_iterable(
        distinct_permutations(valcomb + (0,)*(r-d))
        for valcomb in combinations_with_replacement((-val, +val), d)
    )

print(list(combs_with_zeroes(val=7, d=1, r=2)))
# [(-7, 0), (0, -7), (0, 7), (7, 0)]

print(list(combs_with_zeroes(val=7, d=1, r=3)))
# [(-7, 0, 0), (0, -7, 0), (0, 0, -7), (0, 0, 7), (0, 7, 0), (7, 0, 0)]

print(list(combs_with_zeroes(val=7, d=3, r=4)))
# [(-7, -7, -7, 0), (-7, -7, 0, -7), (-7, 0, -7, -7), (0, -7, -7, -7), (-7, -7, 0, 7), (-7, -7, 7, 0), (-7, 0, -7, 7), (-7, 0, 7, -7), (-7, 7, -7, 0), (-7, 7, 0, -7), (0, -7, -7, 7), (0, -7, 7, -7), (0, 7, -7, -7), (7, -7, -7, 0), (7, -7, 0, -7), (7, 0, -7, -7), (-7, 0, 7, 7), (-7, 7, 0, 7), (-7, 7, 7, 0), (0, -7, 7, 7), (0, 7, -7, 7), (0, 7, 7, -7), (7, -7, 0, 7), (7, -7, 7, 0), (7, 0, -7, 7), (7, 0, 7, -7), (7, 7, -7, 0), (7, 7, 0, -7), (0, 7, 7, 7), (7, 0, 7, 7), (7, 7, 0, 7), (7, 7, 7, 0)]

print(list(combs_with_zeroes(val=7, d=2, r=5)))
# [(-7, -7, 0, 0, 0), (-7, 0, -7, 0, 0), (-7, 0, 0, -7, 0), (-7, 0, 0, 0, -7), (0, -7, -7, 0, 0), (0, -7, 0, -7, 0), (0, -7, 0, 0, -7), (0, 0, -7, -7, 0), (0, 0, -7, 0, -7), (0, 0, 0, -7, -7), (-7, 0, 0, 0, 7), (-7, 0, 0, 7, 0), (-7, 0, 7, 0, 0), (-7, 7, 0, 0, 0), (0, -7, 0, 0, 7), (0, -7, 0, 7, 0), (0, -7, 7, 0, 0), (0, 0, -7, 0, 7), (0, 0, -7, 7, 0), (0, 0, 0, -7, 7), (0, 0, 0, 7, -7), (0, 0, 7, -7, 0), (0, 0, 7, 0, -7), (0, 7, -7, 0, 0), (0, 7, 0, -7, 0), (0, 7, 0, 0, -7), (7, -7, 0, 0, 0), (7, 0, -7, 0, 0), (7, 0, 0, -7, 0), (7, 0, 0, 0, -7), (0, 0, 0, 7, 7), (0, 0, 7, 0, 7), (0, 0, 7, 7, 0), (0, 7, 0, 0, 7), (0, 7, 0, 7, 0), (0, 7, 7, 0, 0), (7, 0, 0, 0, 7), (7, 0, 0, 7, 0), (7, 0, 7, 0, 0), (7, 7, 0, 0, 0)]
```

Note the results become quite long quite fast; the total number of elements is `2**d * (r choose d)`.

Answer (score 2):

Straightforward generalization of your way:

```py
from itertools import combinations, product

val = 7
r = 5
d = 2

for I in combinations(range(r), d):
    for V in product([+val, -val], repeat=d):
        t = [0] * r
        for i, v in zip(I, V):
            t[i] = v
        print(t)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVBJCsJAELzPK_o40QmIIIrgA_KBXEIO0STakEwPnU5Av-LFi_7JP_gIZ1yC1qEORVU11eebO8qB7OVy7aWOV_dHzdQCSsVC1HSArSMW2FG7RVsIku0MOKay34lSQ9HABpaKPS9U6XmuVE0MCaD9C2ku7L7SHBkoo7UCj-BLg-9Tp7Op7zMQe84NcOWqQjZfd4D4A9kshwnwqIUWNDCEohM6nRhIfyKvWIa5Tw6j6BitaInemz_Tvy94Ag)